# Trying to store and get some data using ElasticSearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, gradle, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have this small configuration using ElasticSearch, but since i want to store some data , i am getting the error below: with `repository.save(new FileProperty("12dW", 123.123, "hii"));` P.S. the elasticSearch is runing on the port 9200 using docker

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.UncategorizedElasticsearchException: Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=request [/index/_refresh] contains unrecognized parameter: [ignore_throttled]]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=request [/index/_refresh] contains unrecognized parameter: [ignore_throttled]]]] with root cause

org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=request [/index/_refresh] contains unrecognized parameter: [ignore_throttled]]
```

> FileRepository.java

```
@Repository

public interface FileRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<FileProperty, String> {

    List<FileProperty> findByName(String filename);

}
```

> FileProperty.java

```
@Document(indexName = "index", type = "user", shards = 2)
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FileProperty {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private double filesize;
    private String name;
}
```

> Config.java

public class Config {

```
@Bean
public RestHighLevelClient client() {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration
            = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
            .build();

    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
    return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
}
```

}

> application.yml

```
      # Local Elasticsearch config
        spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
        spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9200
        spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch
        
        elasticsearch.index.name=index
        elasticsearch.user.type=user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using an Elasticsearch client lib in version 6 or 7 to access an Elasticsearch 5 cluster.

Please check the [compatibility matrix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#preface.versions) which versions of Spring Data Elasticsearch and Spring Boot to use with which version of Elasticsearch.

Another thing: You should use

```
spring.elasticsearch.server=localhost:9200
```

to configure where your Elasticsearch cluster is running and remove these two lines:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9200
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch
```

Theses are configuration values for the transport client and Spring Boot will configure one if these properties are set.

Comment: I will try your solution tomorrow. I will remove the mentioned lines and set the versions of springboot on 2.3.x and elasticsearch on 7.6.2 in gradle, will this be fine? I will then accept your solution if every thing works.

Comment: this will not work, if the Elasticsearch cluster you use has not the matching version. What version of Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 7.6.2. And yes i have warning that the cluster does not match. How yo solve this plz

Comment: if the versions differ in the minor version, chances are good that it works without problems. At least in the ES 7 I am not aware of breaking changes in ES between minor version changes